# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. (VB and ACCESS 2013)

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Forgive me for asking this stupid question but...
I really cannot figure out how to solve this syntax error

In my database(which is access 2013) I have this fields in my table

**Fields - Data Types**

NO - Number

RANK - Short Text

LAST NAME - Short Text

FIRST NAME - Short Text

MIDDLE NAME - Short Text

ADDRESS - Short Text

CONTACT NUMBER - Short Text

ACCNT CODE - Short Text

UNIT CODE - Number

ATM ACCNT NUMBER - Number

PENSION TYPE - Short Text

REMARKS - Short Text

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form2

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Retiree.accdb"

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Open()
    End If
    cmd.Connection = con


    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Retiree(NO, RANK, [LAST NAME], [FIRST NAME], [MIDDLE NAME], ADDRESS, [CONTACT NUMBER], [ACCNT CODE], [UNIT CODE], [ATM ACCNT NUMBER], [PENSION TYPE], REMARKS) VALUES(399, 'dfdGDFGF', 'GwejjweDFGF', 'GDfgfgFGF', 'GDFGfgfF', 'GDFfdftertGF', 'GfgdfggfgfgDFGF', 'GdfggfdgvbvDFGF', 1323, 2132, 'GDFgdsfbvsdGF', 'GDsgdfsjjjFGF')"

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    Me.Close()


End Sub


End Class
```

The error message I get is:
Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

I hope someone can point out the syntax error in my code because I really cannot figure out where is it.(Maybe my eyesight is really bad now)

Comment: `NO` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: In general you should always use sql-parameters. @TheBlueDog: it is not, is it? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249061.aspx **Edit** Yes, it is :)

Comment: @Tim Schmelter what do you mean by sql parameters

Comment: @zerenin: [`OleDbParameter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It prevents sql injection or other issues(like date or type conversions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this. All column names put In `[]` brackets. There can be issue that because `No` is reserved word, It should be inside `[]`.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Retiree([NO], [RANK], [LAST NAME], [FIRST NAME], [MIDDLE NAME], [ADDRESS], [CONTACT NUMBER], [ACCNT CODE], [UNIT CODE], [ATM ACCNT NUMBER], [PENSION TYPE], [REMARKS]) VALUES(399, 'dfdGDFGF', 'GwejjweDFGF', 'GDfgfgFGF', 'GDFGfgfF', 'GDFfdftertGF', 'GfgdfggfgfgDFGF', 'GdfggfdgvbvDFGF', 1323, 2132, 'GDFgdsfbvsdGF', 'GDsgdfsjjjFGF')"
```

Comment: @zerenin: or don't use [reserved words](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249061.aspx) as column names in the first place ;)

Comment: Don't forget to select as correct answer. Good luck :)

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas: only `NO` is reserved.