# Syntax error in inserting values in INSERT INTO statement. -VB and ACCESS 2013

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Forgive me again for asking this stupid question again but... I really cannot figure out how to solve this another syntax error in inserting values

In my database(which is access 2013) I have this fields in my table

Fields - Data Types

NO - Number

RANK - Short Text

LAST NAME - Short Text

FIRST NAME - Short Text

MIDDLE NAME - Short Text

ADDRESS - Short Text

CONTACT NUMBER - Short Text

ACCNT CODE - Short Text

UNIT CODE - Number

ATM ACCNT NUMBER - Number

PENSION TYPE - Short Text

REMARKS - Short Text

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form2

  Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Retiree.accdb"

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
      con.Open()
    End If
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Retiree([NO], [RANK], [LAST NAME], [FIRST NAME], [MIDDLE NAME], [ADDRESS], [CONTACT NUMBER], [ACCNT CODE], [UNIT CODE], [ATM ACCNT NUMBER], [PENSION TYPE], [REMARKS]) VALUES(" & num & ",'" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & RichTextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox16.Text & "','" & TextBox15.Text & "'," & TextBox14.Text & "," & TextBox13.Text & ",'" & TextBox12.Text & "','" & TextBox1.Text & "')"

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    Me.Close()

  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you use `Parameterized Query` you will likely fix the error and lose the risk of SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Given the way you're assembling your query, you will be susceptible to all sorts of errors occurring because of the content of the data. Start by displaying the actual query that gives you an error and work from there.

Comment: How can I Parametized my query?? and how can I display the actual query that gives an error. Sorry Im noob at programming in vb. I hope you can explain it for me. Advance thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. (VB and ACCESS 2013)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895789/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-vb-and-access-2013)

Comment: it may consider duplicate but my problem here is the values that I insert. It gives me a syntax error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the text boxes and the rich text box could be causing the syntax error.  Here is what I suggest:

Edit the the insert statement and don't include any of the text box or rich text values, just use "" (empty string) for those columns.  If that works, it means the content of the text box or rich text box is causing the syntax error.

Start adding back in the text box and rich text values, one a a time, until you get the syntax error.  Then you will see which one is causing the problem.  It very well be may the rich text box.

This isn't a good way to code the insert statement, because if the user puts a single quote in any of the text boxes, you are going to get a SQL syntax error.  You would need to remove the single quotes from the user entered data in code, or, better, use parameters for the user entered data so it doesn't impact the syntax of the statement.

If all else fails, provide us the content of the cmd.CommandText property after that line of code has executed but before the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() has been executed, this way we can see the full and real SQL statement being executed, then we can see the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I Parametized my query??

You can use code similar to this:

```vb
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText =
            "INSERT INTO Retiree ([NO], [RANK], [LAST NAME], [FIRST NAME], [MIDDLE NAME], [ADDRESS], [CONTACT NUMBER], [ACCNT CODE], [UNIT CODE], [ATM ACCNT NUMBER], [PENSION TYPE], [REMARKS]) " &
            "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = num  ' [NO]
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255).Value = TextBox4.Text  ' [RANK]
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255).Value = TextBox3.Text  ' [LAST NAME]
    ' ... and so on
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255).Value = TextBox1.Text  ' [REMARKS]
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Haha :) Ok I figure out my problem. I just need to convert the content of the textbox into int that is suppose to be the inserted value of a field which data type is number

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Retiree([NO], [RANK], [LAST NAME], [FIRST NAME], [MIDDLE NAME], [ADDRESS], [CONTACT NUMBER], [ACCNT CODE], [UNIT CODE], [ATM ACCNT NUMBER], [PENSION TYPE], [REMARKS]) VALUES(" & num & ",'" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & RichTextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox16.Text & "','" & TextBox15.Text & "'," & Convert.ToInt32(TextBox14.Text) & "," & Convert.ToInt32(TextBox13.Text) & ",'" & TextBox12.Text & "','" & TextBox1.Text & "') "
```

But still I want to know how can I parametized this to prevent sql injection